# Reference Image on SASS

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass

I've been trying to set a background-image to my Rails app using SASS however when I try:

```
.header {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background-image: image-url("sky.png") no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

The image is not loaded but when I try:

```
background-image: image-url("sky.png");
```

The image loads partialy. Anyone have any idea why this is happening? How can I fix this?

**EDIT**

CSS File:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.vert-text {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.vert-text h1 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 4.5em;
  font-weight: 700;
}

/* Side Menu */

#sidebar-wrapper {
  margin-right: -250px;
  right: 0;
  width: 250px;
  background: #000;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  z-index: 1000;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}

.sidebar-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 250px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
  line-height: 40px;
  text-indent: 20px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
  color: #999999;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
  height: 55px;
  line-height: 55px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
  color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: none;
}

#menu-toggle {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
}

#sidebar-wrapper.active {
  right: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}

.toggle {
  margin: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

/* Full Page Image Header Area */

.header {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: image-url("sky.png") no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

/* Intro */

.intro {
  padding: 50px 0;
}

/* Services */

.services {
  background: #7fbbda;
  padding: 50px 0;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.service-item {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

i.service-icon {
  border: 3px solid #ffffff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 56px;
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  line-height: 136px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Callout */

.callout {
  color: #ffffff;
  display: table;
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  background: image-url("footimage.png") no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

/* Portfolio */

.portfolio {
  padding: 50px 0;
}

.portfolio-item {
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.img-portfolio {
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/* Call to Action */

.call-to-action {
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #0a5175;
  padding: 50px 0;
}

.call-to-action .btn {
  margin: 10px;
}

/* Map */

.map {
  height: 500px;
}

/* Footer */

footer {
  padding: 100px 0;
}

.top-scroll {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.top-scroll a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

i.scroll {
  color: #333333;
}

i.scroll:hover {
  color: #0a5175;
}
/* Responsive */

@media (max-width: 768px) {

  .header {
        background: image-url("sky.png") no-repeat center center fixed;
  }

  .callout {
        background: image-url("footimage.png") no-repeat center center fixed;
  }

  .map {
        height: 75%;
  }

}
```

Comment: i do not think it is a problem with sass. it might be a problem with css itself. can you create a jsfiddle with the html and css?

Comment: What do you mean by "partially load"?

Comment: It loads 1/3 of the image total size

Comment: *All* of this CSS is necessary to reproduce the problem?  You're going to need to provide a demo.  As it stands, the problem is unclear or not reproducible.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JU8ac/. Does this help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found you were having the same issue as me and after hours and hours of digging I finally figured out how to fix the 1/3 image issue.   I am not a developer and this maybe totally wrong but in the css included with stylish-portfolio there is a section call .text-vertical-center  I did not see it in your .css in the initial posting.  Well to get the image to display correctly I found you need to add

```
height: 963px;
```

That fixed the issue for me.  I see its been months since you posted this but I really hope it helps you or someone else.   If it isn't the correct way of displaying the image in .css please feel free to leave me comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage it like this;

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vN5FL/)**

**css**

```
html {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image:url("https://www.google.co.in/logos/doodles/2014/dian-fosseys-82nd-birthday-5702250374627328-hp.jpg");
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  position:fixed;
}
```

Comment: This code totally re-arranged my css. What I'm trying to do in my app is this (http://startbootstrap.com/templates/stylish-portfolio/index.html). The only thing not loading is the main image.

Answer (score 0):

the following `css` helps you

```
html,body{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}


.header {
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  position: relative;
  background: url("desert.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Using only background: the image was loaded but only partialy. When using the code that you posted my css was totally rearranged. I'll edit my question to include my full css.